# What is the (economic, social) value of STEM archives?

Tags: computation, social

I'm trying to convince my institution to improve their internal Computer Science archives, and want one of my argument angles to be based on empirical value-adds of archiving. History, library science, etc are not my area of domain knowledge at all.

Is there any empirical or quantified research in the economic, social, or other benefits of archives? STEM and Computational archives are of interest in particular.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want your institution to archive? Or, do you want your institution to provide access to, e.g., Web of Science?

Comment: The former. The university is a leader in tech development & robotics but has no system for attempting to archive potentially historically critical hardware and software.